# .Net control links not working on deployment

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-server-2008, server

I have deployed my code base to a testing server.  All of my links now are not clickable.  They can be right clicked on, and work fine with opening in a new tab, but not just regular clicking.

Am I missing some really obvious setting on the new server?

Other sites on this server are OK so it's not browser specific. I'm using WinForms.

Comment: "I'm using WinForms" or webforms??

Comment: Are you using a WinForms WebBrowser control?  Try opening the site in other browsers, if they links work in Chrome/FireFox it's probably not an issue with your site.  If it is a WebBrowser control you're probably getting a JavaScript error (or another error on the page).  There is a property called "ScriptErrorsSuppressed", set that to false to see those errors.